# How to close Vuetify Expansion Panel programatically?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify navigation drawer and inside that i have a `v-expansion-panel`. Now i can open one of the panels in the `v-expansion-panel` but how i can set it up so that when i close the navigation drawer, the expansion panels should close as well. Right now they stay opened even if the drawer closes?

Here is a sample [pen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/YzyVWNW)

Here is the demo:-

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: null,
      panel: true
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout justfy-center>
        <v-flex>
          <v-btn @click.stop="drawer = !drawer">Toggle</v-btn>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" temporary right absolute>
      <v-expansion-panel v-model="panel" popout>
        <v-expansion-panel-content v-for="(item,i) in 5" :key="i">
          <template v-slot:header>
            <div>Item</div>
          </template>
          <v-card>
            <v-card-text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-expansion-panel-content>
      </v-expansion-panel>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels/) says, the `value` property (which is bound with `v-model="panel"` in your pen) "Controls the opened/closed state of content in the expansion-panel. Corresponds to a zero-based index of the currently opened content. If the `multiple` prop (previously `expand` in 1.5.x) is used then it is an array of numbers where each entry corresponds to the index of the opened content. The index order is not relevant."

So you just need to update the `value` of the expansion panel to set none to active when the `value` of the navigation drawer changes to false.  One way to do this is with a watcher

```js
  watch: {
    drawer(newValue) {
      if (!newValue) {
        this.panel = -1;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a watcher that will set the `panel` to `false` whenever the `drawer` changes it state.
eg:

```
watch: {
  drawer: function(){
    this.panel = false
 }
}
```